# Query All Tables In PostgreSQL Database For Text

Tags: postgresql

I do not have write privilges on the database so I can not create a proc to run.  I was originally going to use this function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION search_columns(
    needle text,
    haystack_tables name[] default '{}',
    haystack_schema name[] default '{}'
)
RETURNS table(schemaname text, tablename text, columnname text, rowctid text)
AS $$
begin
  FOR schemaname,tablename,columnname IN
      SELECT c.table_schema,c.table_name,c.column_name
      FROM information_schema.columns c
      JOIN information_schema.tables t ON
        (t.table_name=c.table_name AND t.table_schema=c.table_schema)
      WHERE (c.table_name=ANY(haystack_tables) OR haystack_tables='{}')
        AND (c.table_schema=ANY(haystack_schema) OR haystack_schema='{}')
        AND t.table_type='BASE TABLE'
  LOOP
    EXECUTE format('SELECT ctid FROM %I.%I WHERE cast(%I as text)=%L',
       schemaname,
       tablename,
       columnname,
       needle
    ) INTO rowctid;
    IF rowctid is not null THEN
      RETURN NEXT;
    END IF;
 END LOOP;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

but I need a way to scan all fields in all tables to search for the keywoard '%mxltw%' how can this be done w/o dumping the data and w/o creating a stored proc?

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate the whole list of SQL statements to be run in a single SQL file and run this SQL file with psql.